Get Intellij and Eclipse to format for loop in the same way
Intellij cannot be made to format a for loop without a space before the final parenthesis:
for (i = props.getChildProperties().keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

Intellij will always make it
for (i = props.getChildProperties().keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

And Eclipse can be configured to insert this space using
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_for" value="insert"/>

But then Eclipse ALWAYS inserts the space
for (Object o : props.getChildProperties().keySet() ) {

I can accept either space or no space in the classic for loop, but the enhanced for loop must not have a space before the final parenthesis.
How can I achieve this without using IDE plugins? Editorconfig also acceptable.
Eclipse also has this setting
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_semicolon_in_for" value="insert"/>

but this refers to the first semicolon not the second.
There is a checkstyle rule to control this sort of thing
https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks/whitespace/emptyforiteratorpad.html

Would for (i = props.getChildProperties().keySet().iterator();i.hasNext();) { work (with no space after either ;)?

@dan1st its reads terribly, so no

This may be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-288050 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-34375/Java-Formatter-Respect-space-after-semicolon-setting-for-for-loop-with-empty-after-loop-operation.

If you want to extend the Eclipse Java formatter by an option for a space when there is no update part in the for loop, provide a pull request.
